# Calculate the sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can anyone help me with this:
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{3}{7^n}$? I had the idea to take the number 3 in front of the sum, and get the $q$ of the geometric series, $q = \frac{1}{7}$. I'm not sure if i should choose the $\frac{q}{1-q}$ or the $\frac{1}{1-q}$ formula. Could you help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, we have $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3}{7^n}$$$$=3\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{7^n}$$ $$=3\left(\frac{1}{7}+\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^3+\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^4+\ldots \right)$$

$$=3\left(\text{sum of infinite G.P. with first term}\ \frac{1}{7} \ \text{& common ratio}\ \frac{1}{7} \right)$$
$$=3\left(\frac{\frac{1}{7}}{1-\frac{1}{7}} \right)$$
$$=3\left(\frac{\frac{1}{7}}{\frac{6}{7}} \right)$$
$$=3\left(\frac{1}{6} \right)=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

If $|q|<1$

$$\frac{1}{1-q}=1+q+q^2+\cdots$$

or

$$\frac{q}{1-q}=q+q^2+q^3\cdots$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{3}{7^n}=\frac{3}{7}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{7^{n-1}}=\frac{3}{7}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{7^{n}}$$
$$=\frac{3}{7}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{7}}=\frac{3}{7-1}=\frac{1}{2}$$